# Unsteady Rankine-Hugoniot relations. Is it applicable?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, shock-waves

For a unsteady normal shock moving in a medium, the [Rankine-Hugoniot relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine%E2%80%93Hugoniot_conditions) can be derived, by converting the problem into a steady by fixing the frame of reference on the shock. 
This idea is easy to follow, given the shock is uniform and steady, meaning the shock strength ($\rho_2/\rho_1$) does not change with  time.

Recently, I came across a relation for density and velocity as a function of time for a shock whose pressure jump decays exponentially with time. How can one derive this?

\begin{align}
\rho(t)&=\rho_0\frac{(\gamma+1)p(t)+2\gamma p_0}{(\gamma-1)p(t)+2\gamma p_0} \\
u(t)&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\gamma p_0}}\frac{a_0p(t)}{\sqrt{(\gamma+1)p(t)+2\gamma p_0}}
\end{align}

Comment: *Recently, I came across...* Can you provide the reference?

Comment: Also, are $a_0$ and $p_0$ the downstream speed of sound and pressure, respectively?

Comment: @kyleKanos a0 and p0 are upstream(I guess, otherwise the equation becomes implicit). The expression was given in a thesis[link](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/mechengdiss/5/) page 21

Comment: @kyleKanos also check this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0734743X1000120X). They have expressed velocity as a function of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Background**

The link to the dissertation you provided gives a derivation in Appendix A through the following steps.

First, start with the general [Rankine-Hugoniot relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine-Hugoniot_conditions) for a simple normal incidence hydrodynamic [shock wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave), where:
$$
\frac{ \rho_{dn} }{ \rho_{up} } = \frac{ u_{up} }{ u_{dn} } = \frac{ \left( \gamma + 1 \right) M_{up}^{2} }{ \left( \gamma + 1 \right) + \left( \gamma - 1 \right) \left( M_{up}^{2} - 1 \right) } \\
\frac{ P_{dn} }{ P_{up} } = \frac{ \left( \gamma + 1 \right) + 2 \gamma \left( M_{up}^{2} - 1 \right) }{ \left( \gamma + 1 \right) }
$$
where $\rho$ is the mass density, $u$ is the flow speed along the shock normal vector, $\gamma$ is the [ratio of specific heats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio), $M$ is the [Mach number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_number), and $up$($dn$) corresponds to the average value in the upstream(downstream) regions.

## **Derivation of Density Ratio**

If we rewrite the second equation above by solving for $M_{up}$ we get:
$$
M_{up}^{2} = \frac{ P_{up} \left( \gamma - 1 \right) + P_{dn} \left( \gamma + 1 \right) }{ 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} }
$$

You will notice that this can be rewritten as:
$$
M_{up}^{2} = \left( \frac{ P_{dn} }{ P_{up} } - 1 \right) \frac{ \gamma + 1 }{ 2 \ \gamma } + 1
$$

The physically important leap comes when you recognize that the 1 in the ()'s above represents a system no different than the original, namely undisturbed.  That means that all other terms are part of the disturbed media, which the authors call the *overpressure* part of the expression.  Thus, we can define the overpressure as $P_{s} = P_{dn} - P_{up}$ so that we have:
$$
M_{up}^{2} = \frac{ P_{s} }{ P_{up} } \left( \frac{ \gamma + 1 }{ 2 \ \gamma } \right) + 1
$$

So if we substitute this version of $M_{up}$ into our expression for the density ratio above we get:
$$
\frac{ \rho_{dn} }{ \rho_{up} } = \frac{ \left( \gamma + 1 \right) P_{s} + 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} }{ \left( \gamma - 1 \right) P_{s} + 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} }
$$
then we can see that we just replace $Q_{s} \rightarrow Q\left( t \right)$ and $Q_{up} \rightarrow Q_{o}$ to get your expression, where $Q$ is any of the changing quantities.

## **Derivation of Speed Ratio**

The first thing to do is to just invert the expression for $\rho_{dn}$ above to get:
$$
\frac{ u_{dn} }{ u_{up} } = \frac{ \left( \gamma - 1 \right) P_{s} + 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} }{ \left( \gamma + 1 \right) P_{s} + 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} }
$$
and we then note that $u_{up} = M_{up} a_{up}$, where $a_{j}$ is the sound speed in the $j^{th}$ region.  If we substitute the new expression for $u_{up}$ and the overpressure version of $M_{up}$ we get:
$$
u_{up} = a_{up} \sqrt{ \frac{ P_{s} }{ P_{up} } \left( \frac{ \gamma + 1 }{ 2 \ \gamma } \right) + 1 } \\
= a_{up} \sqrt{ \frac{ P_{s} \left( \gamma + 1 \right) + 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} }{ 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} } }
$$
which gives us:
$$
u_{dn} = \frac{ a_{up} }{ \sqrt{ 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} } } \left[ \frac{ \left( \gamma - 1 \right) P_{s} + 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} }{ \sqrt{ \left( \gamma + 1 \right) P_{s} + 2 \ \gamma \ P_{up} } } \right]
$$

## **Differences**

I am fairly certain they have missed or dropped a term in their expression for $u\left( t \right)$ because even *Mathematica*<sup>TM</sup> cannot equate the terms in their equation A.8.  I tried deriving their results several different ways, even letting *Mathematica* do all the work just in case I made a mistake and I continually get my result shown above.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the knowledge. I cannot up vote you as I have insufficient rep.